# Why doesn't my terminal display this character?

Tags: command-line, utf-8

I like to run `emacs` in terminal, which is `rxvt-unicode-256color`.

In the terminal my `/etc/i3status.conf` displays this:

[image]

However, when I run `emacs` outside of my terminal the same file is displayed like this:

[image]

So it seems that my terminal has a problem displaying `UTF-8` characters. Why am I having this problem and how can I fix it?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with crouton on a chromebook.

Issuing `locale` gives

[image]

Running `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` changes all of the `"POSIX"` to `"en_US.UTF-8"`. However, the file in question still does not properly display the character in question. Instead it displays as

[image]

Comment: Please add the output of `locale` command

Comment: Run `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and then check..

Comment: @heemayl Running the command doesn't fix the problem. I updated the problem with the results.

Comment: i believe thats a german char?

Comment: @heemayl Isn't it supposed to display as a sharp s?

Comment: Try `export LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"`

Comment: Running <code>export LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"</code> results in the same output.

Comment: Actually, issuing <code>export LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"</code> in a new terminal gives an error: <code>bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (de_DE.UTF-8): No such file or directory</code>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22749/discussion-between-heemayl-and-brian-fitzpatrick).